# Distance Calculation for Cluster Analysis

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to run Cluster Analysis for my WorldClim data. My dataset has 236.000 rows. When I'm try to run `dist` code, R is going crazy and I have to shut it down. I googled it and found this was because CPU. I found a solution [here](http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/clustering/hierarchical-cluster-analysis) but I got this error

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package 'rpud' is not available (for R version 3.2.0)
```

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package has been [archieved](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpud/index.html) . You could try downloading the [package](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rpud/rpud_0.0.2.tar.gz) and installing from source. The big problem with this package is that it need s `nvcc` to use the cuda GPU. Use the power of Google for `nvcc` installation instructions.

If you are using Windows, you'll need Rtools

Comment: It did not work. 
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
* installing *source* package 'rpud' ...
checking "environment variable CUDA_HOME"... "CUDA_HOME not set; using default /usr/local/cuda"
checking for /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc... no
configure: error: "cannot find nvcc; check CUDA install"ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rpud'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rpud'

Comment: Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package '/Users/ismail_b/Downloads/rpud_0.0.2.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status

Comment: You need `nvcc`. Try googling `nvcc Mac` It doesn't look straightforward